# Waiting list and confirmation for trains in India

Tags: trains, tickets, india

I've booked a ticket to Belgaum for today but it shows `WL/44`.

Does that mean I'm on a waiting list? Should I cancel the ticket or go to railway station and check?

Comment: Where are you travelling from? On which train?

Comment: Where on the ticket does it say that? Any chance you could post a photo of the ticket so we can see?

Comment: A web search suggests that it does indeed mean you are on a waiting list. Apparently, you might still be able to board the train if there are more cancellations before departure.

Comment: Duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/indian-trains-wait-list-will-i-get-a-seat?rq=1 See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/indian-railways-online-reservation-rules/7431#7431

Answer (score 0):

WL/44 means your ticket is not yet confirmed and 1 hour before from train strats you have to cancel the ticket. thats depends on your emergency and by the same time if you can able to get other train or bus its better to cancel that ticket.

Comment: you mean he has to cancel it only if it is not confirmed by then I suppose? This is not clear at all

Comment: If it is an e-ticket, the ticket will be automatically cancelled and fare will be refunded back if the ticket is not confirmed.